# Text goes under the header in html/css

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website using html and php. I have created a fixed header for the home page with links that lead to the different part of the page with the help of internal linking.
But when I am doing this the text goes under the header, for eg: if I am using the about page, when I click the about link it takes me to the about content but the linked word (in this case about) gets under the header.

Please suggest some code to fix this problem.

Comment: If you mean `position:fixed` then it will take the element out of the flow, and therefore the other elements won't know it's there as such, so you'll need to set a top margin of whatever the header height is to the content, or whatever element comes after the header.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5zNcQ/9/

You add vertical space on top that pushes the main container downwards. This space should be at least the height of the fixed container.

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
header ul li {
    display: inline;
}
main {
    padding-top: 120px;
}
main p {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
main p:first-child {
    margin:0;
}
```